# Linux Connect to Windows 10 Share (SMB1 succeeds, SMB2 fails)

Tags: linux, networking, mount, network-shares, smb

Problem description: Linux mounting SMB1 on a Windows 10 computer works as follows because "SMB1 Support" is enabled:

```
mount -t cifs -o user=USER,password=USER,vers=1.0 //192.168.1.222/SHARE /tmp/test
```

When I disable "SMB1 support" on the Windows 10 machine AND type at `vers=2.0` or `2.1`, I get the following error message back from the SSH console:

> failed: Host is down

Can you please help me to find the correct command line to "negotiate" modern SMB2 shares on a modern computing environment?

Comment: I will think about this.  I connect Ubuntu 22.04 and Kali 2023.2 to Windows 11 Pro with SMB2 .    I do not have SMB1 on my Windows 11 box.   I connect with SMB;//IPaddress/Shareddrive

Comment: [Edit] your question to clarify which version of the Linux kernel you are using.

Comment: Would be interested in understanding which CIFS driver your using exactly

Comment: Kernel is: uname -r
3.18.44  -  and sorry I don´t know the command for checking the driver, but will google and see what I can find.